# show sale error datatime ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-3

Tengo un campo datetime y el guarda normal pero renderiza al show me sale este error

Este es el error: .to_s("%d-%m-%Y")
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**show.html.erb**

```
    <%= @snack.fecha_entrega.to_s("%d-%m-%Y")%>
```

form

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <%= label_tag :fecha_entrega, '4.Fecha  y hora de Entrega' %>
  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="">
    <%= f.text_field :fecha_entrega, class: 'form-control deshabilitar ' %>
     <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

** otro diferente**

```
 <%= @snack.fecha_entrega.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")%>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ...pero cual es el error?

Comment: @AlterLagos hola este es  .to_s("%d-%m-%Y")  es lo que sale pues .to_s gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar un pantallazo del error? porque eso que indicas no existe como error, tiene que salir algo más con un backtrace de donde se origina. Una suposición, pero ¿no estarás queriendo usar .strftime en vez de .to_s?

Comment: @AlterLagos  hola , ya actualice el código, gracias

Comment: @AlterLagos  gracias como seria con minutos, medio resultado,  pero  como son para los minutos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu fecha de entrega viene nula. Deberías poner:

```
<%= @snack.fecha_entrega.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") if @snack.fecha_entrega %>
```

o también te serviría

```
<%= @snack.fecha_entrega.try(:strftime, "%d-%m-%Y") %>
```

Comment: gracias como seria con minutos.

Comment: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime